# RadSideDrawer not displaying

Tags: android, xaml, telerik, xamarin.forms

All I'm getting is a Yellow screen where I'm expecting and part lime and red screen.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:telerikPrimitives="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.Primitives;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Primitives"
         xmlns:telerik="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.DataControls"
         x:Class="Manager.ControlScreen" Title="Menu"  >
<Grid x:Name="grd" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
<telerikPrimitives:RadSideDrawer x:Name="rsd" DrawerLength="250" IsVisible="True" DrawerTransitionDuration="2" DrawerTransitionType="SlideAlong"  IsEnabled="True" IsOpen="True" DrawerLocation="Left" AreGesturesEnabled="True" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
  <telerikPrimitives:RadSideDrawer.DrawerContent >
    <Grid BackgroundColor="Lime">
    </Grid>
  </telerikPrimitives:RadSideDrawer.DrawerContent>
  <telerikPrimitives:RadSideDrawer.MainContent>
    <Grid  BackgroundColor="Red">
    </Grid>
  </telerikPrimitives:RadSideDrawer.MainContent>
</telerikPrimitives:RadSideDrawer>
</Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

I have included all the telerik android libraries but no matter what I do, I can't get it to draw I tried adding contents like buttons and labels but they wouldn't draw either. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.